# Type issue in React CloneElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using React Children and React Clone element with goal of triggering methods both in wrapper and Select components at onClick event in the Option component. Everything is working fine. But I am getting type error where I call Option component.

Code:

```
import React, {
  useState,
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
  Children,
  cloneElement,
  ReactElement,
  ReactNode
} from "react";

type OptionProps = {
  setSelectedInSelect: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
  setSelectedInWrapper: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
  fruit: string;
};

function Option({
  setSelectedInSelect,
  setSelectedInWrapper,
  fruit
}: OptionProps) {
  return (
    <li
      onClick={() => {
        setSelectedInSelect(fruit);
        setSelectedInWrapper(fruit);
      }}
    >
      {fruit}
    </li>
  );
}

type SelectProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

function Select({ children }: SelectProps) {
  const [selectedInSelect, setSelectedInSelect] = useState<string>("");
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>selected in select: {selectedInSelect}</div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        {Children.map(children, (child) => {
          return cloneElement(child as ReactElement, {
            setSelectedInSelect
          });
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

function Wrapper() {
  const [selectedInWrapper, setSelectedInWrapper] = useState<string>("");

  const fruits = ["Apple", "Orange"];

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "20px" }}>
      <div style={{ marginBottom: "15px" }}>
        <div>selected in wrapper: {selectedInWrapper}</div>
      </div>
      <Select>
        {fruits.map((fruit) => {
          return (
            <Option // ERROR HERE
              key={fruit}
              fruit={fruit}
              setSelectedInWrapper={setSelectedInWrapper}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Wrapper;
```

The error is:
`Property 'setSelectedInSelect' is missing in type '{ key: string; fruit: string; setSelectedInWrapper: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>; }' but required in type 'OptionProps'.`

The `setSelectedInSelect` is passed to Option when I am cloning the component. How can I get rid of the type issue?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-swartz-fjnkm?file=/src/Select.tsx

Comment: Any chance moving this code to a sandbox to reproduce the error?

Comment: @DennisVash Added codesandbox link at the end of post.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping the same thing twice in the state, why don't you pass it from the wrapper to select as a prop? This way you don't need the second call and don't need to clone anything
type OptionProps = {
setSelectedInWrapper: Dispatch<SetStateAction>;
fruit: string;
};

```
    function Option({
      setSelectedInWrapper,
      fruit
    }: OptionProps) {
      return (
        <li
          onClick={() => {
            setSelectedInWrapper(fruit);
          }}
        >
          {fruit}
        </li>
      );
    }

    type SelectProps = {
      children: ReactNode;
      selectedFruit: string
    };

    function Select({ children,selectedFruit }: SelectProps) {
     return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>selected in select: {selectedFruit}</div>
          </div>
          <ul>
            {children}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }

    function Wrapper() {
      const [selectedInWrapper, setSelectedInWrapper] = useState<string>("");

      const fruits = ["Apple", "Orange"];

      return (
        <div style={{ margin: "20px" }}>
          <div style={{ marginBottom: "15px" }}>
            <div>selected in wrapper: {selectedInWrapper}</div>
          </div>
          <Select selectedFruit={selectedInWrapper}>
            {fruits.map((fruit) => {
              return (
                <Option
                  key={fruit}
                  fruit={fruit}
                  setSelectedInWrapper={setSelectedInWrapper}
                />
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nadia, but how to pass some entirely different prop or function from the Select to Option? How would I solve the type issue? That is the main issue I am facing.

Comment: I advise you to re-consider your approach, but if you absolutely have to do it you can do something like adding `setSelectedInSelect={null!}` to Options